# How to Send Foreign key id along with Form data in angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'mm creating an Angular application with ASP.NET.

I need to create:

- `course`s,
- `course content`s
- `course schedule`s for the selected `course`.

After creating the `course` I will select that particular `course` and create the content for that.

But while submitting the form, I also need to save the **selected course id** as a foreign key in database.

Can anyone help me on this please?

#### createcontent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CoursesService } from 'src/app/shared/courses.service';
import { Content } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-createcontent',
  templateUrl: './createcontent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createcontent.component.css']
})
export class CreatecontentComponent implements OnInit {

  contentForm: FormGroup;
  contents:Content[];
  courseName: string;
  courseid;
  isSubmitted:boolean;

  constructor(private courseservice:CoursesService,private fb: FormBuilder,private route:ActivatedRoute,private http:HttpClient) { 
  }
  setValue(){
    this.contentForm.setValue({  
      courseid:this.route.snapshot.params['id']
  
    });  
  } 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courseName=this.route.snapshot.params['cname'];
    this.courseid=this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    this.contentForm = this.fb.group({
      contentname: ['', Validators.required ],
      contentdescription: ['', Validators.required ],
      duration: ['', Validators.required ],
      courseid:['']

   });
   this.courseservice
   .getContents()
   .subscribe((data: Content[]) => {
     this.contents = data;

 });
}
OnSubmit(){
  console.log(this.contentForm);
  this.http.post('https://localhost:44319/api/contents1',this.contentForm.value,this.courseid).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
}

  }
```

#### createtraining.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CoursesService } from 'src/app/shared/courses.service';
import { Course } from 'src/app/shared/course.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-createtraining',
  templateUrl: './createtraining.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createtraining.component.css']
})
export class CreatetrainingComponent implements OnInit {

  courseForm: FormGroup;
  courses: Course[];
  loading:false;
  toggleState:boolean= false;
  coursename = 'angular';
  clickedCourse:string;
  dayFinished:boolean=true;
  constructor(private courseservice:CoursesService,private fb: FormBuilder,private http:HttpClient) { 
  }
  getCourse(course:string){
    this.clickedCourse=course;
  }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
        coursename: ['', Validators.required ],
        coursedescription: ['', Validators.required ]
     });
      this.courseservice
            .getCourses()
            .subscribe((data: Course[]) => {
            this.courses = data;
            this.toggleState=true;

        });

    }
    OnSubmit(){
      console.log(this.courseForm);
      this.http.post('https://localhost:44319/api/courses',this.courseForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }
```

#### cretecontent.component.html

```
<div id="training-page" class="row">
    <div class="col s8 offset-s2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="sm-jumbotron center-align">
                <h2>Create Content for {{courseName}}</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card">
            <form [formGroup]="contentForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
                <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input name="course_name" id="register-firstname" formControlName="contentname" type="text" class="form-input form-control" #contentname>
                    <label for="course_name" class="center-align">Topic Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['contentname'].invalid && (contentForm.controls['contentname'].dirty || contentForm.controls['contentname'].touched)">
                    <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['contentname'].errors.required" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
                      Topic Name is required.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input name="coursedesc" id="course-description" type="text" formControlName="contentdescription" class="form-input form-control" #contentdescription>
                    <label for="course_description" class="center-align">Topic Description<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['contentdescription'].invalid && (contentForm.controls['contentdescription'].dirty || contentForm.controls['contentdescription'].touched)">
                        <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['contentdescription'].errors.required" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
                          Topic Description is required.
                        </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
                
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input name="contenttime" id="course-description" type="text" formControlName="duration" class="form-input form-control" #duration>
                    <label for="course_description" class="center-align">Duration<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['duration'].invalid && (contentForm.controls['duration'].dirty || contentForm.controls['duration'].touched)">
                        <div *ngIf="contentForm.controls['duration'].errors.required" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
                          Duration is required.
                        </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="courseid" formControlName="courseid" class="form-input form-control" #courseid>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12 valign center">
                    <button [disabled]="!contentForm.valid" (click)="setValue()" type="submit" class="btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Topic Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Topic Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Duration</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let content of contents">
                <td>{{ content.contentname }}</td>
                <td>{{ content.contentdescription }}</td>
                <td>{{ content.duration}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 valign center">
                <button type="button" class="btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/trainer']">Back to Course</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using .net as you backend API, I would strongly recommend you use EF relationships to handle the FK insertion. That way all related data will be pulled through its navigation properties. I appreciate this comment is a bit high level. Here is a tutorial.

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx